# Create A Column Of Values By Splitting An Increasing Value Column

Tags: r, function, lapply, numeric, cut

I have a data frame that contains a seconds column that is a numeric value e.g 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 etc. This column runs to over 6000 seconds .

```
ID  Seconds  F
A     0      0
A    0.1     0
A    0.2     0
A    0.3     0
A    0.4     1
A    0.5     1
A    0.6     1
A    0.7     1
A    0.8     2
```

I am trying to create a new column that splits this value into chunks of 60 seconds (1 minute) so the DF should look similar to this:

```
ID  Seconds  F  Mins
A    0       0   1
A    0.1     0   1
A    0.2     0   1
A    0.3     0   1
A    0.4     1   1
A    0.5     1   1
A    0.6     1   1
A    0.7     1   1
A    0.8     2   1
A    60.1    106 2
A    60.2    106 2
A    60.3    107 2
A    60.4    107 2
A    60.5    108 2
A    60.6    109 2
A    60.7    110 2
A    60.8    110 2
A    60.9    110 2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use integer division `%/%` to get *minutes form seconds*.

```
c(0, 0.1, 59.9, 60, 60.1, 119, 120) %/% 60
#[1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 2
```